# check if a div has controls Javascript

Tags: javascript

i use alert to check if a div has any child controls:

```
alert(document.getElementById("MainContent_imgContainer").hasChildNodes());
```

and this always returns true even if the MainContent_imgContainer div doesn't have any child controls,

please tell me what is the better way to determine if a div has child controls.. thanks

Comment: the method is correct, verify it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your container has a space, which counts as a textNode. Ensure your div is really empty.

Or use another mechanism, e.g. jQuery, that only counts non-textNodes

```
$("#MainContent_imgContainer").children().length; // 0 when empty
```

Comment: thanks very much @WillemM, while the hasChildNodes() always returns true, the children().length really tells me if there's any child. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.children.length` instead which is supported across all browsers. [**MDN Docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.children)

```
alert(document.getElementById("MainContent_imgContainer").children.length > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `.length` of the selector to see how many elements it matched, in this case:

```
if($("#divid").children().length) {
  //child exists
}
```

Comment: this doesn't check if a child exists, but only if the selector returned elements...